# How can I insert multiple values alongside a SQL except clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert three rows into a table using

```
insert into MyLookupTable ([Key1],[Key2])
    values (165072, 1048), (165072, 47), (165072, 46)
```

but I want to make sure they don't exist in the same statement, so was trying `EXCEPT`

```
insert into MyLookupTable ([Key1],[Key2])
    values (165072, 1048), (165072, 47), (165072, 46)
    except select * from MyLookupTable where Key1 = 165072
```

This causes a syntax error!

Then I was thinking I have to use select for my values instead of defining them like above, and insert them that way, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ...) v(key1, key2)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know better than that, I was rushing out the door and didn't realise the 2nd tag hand't selected

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, even though that's really simple, it is actually new syntax to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
insert into MyLookupTable ([Key1], [Key2])
    select v.key1, v.key2
    from (values (165072, 1048), (165072, 47), (165072, 46)) v(key1, key2)
    where not exists (select 1 from MyLookupTable t where t.key1 = v.key1);
```

This checks for just the value of `key1`, which is apparently what you want to do.  If you want to check both, then include both in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

using your example with `except`.

```
insert into MyLookupTable ([Key1],[Key2])
select
    *
from
    (values
        (165072, 1048),
        (165072, 47),
        (165072, 46)
    ) as a([Key1],[Key2])

    except

    select
        [Key1],
        [Key2]
    from
        MyLookupTable
    where
        Key1 = 165072
```